# Queria saber en que falla mi método para encontrar el planeta mas cercano al sol en mi código

Tags: c#

El programa para almacenar diversos planetas introducidos mediante el teclado, y de esos planetas introducidos el programa tiene que mostrarme el mas cercano al sol...
Este es la método que debería devolver el planeta más cercano al sol de entre los ya introducidos mediante teclado

```
void FindClosest(T_PLANET *v, int n, T_PLANET *p_closest)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    j=0;
    for (i=1; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (v[i].data.distance>v[j].data.distance)
        {
            j=i;
        }
    }
    p_closest= &(v[j]);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Creo que el problema lo tienes en el `if`.

Si observas bien, estás buscando el más alejado, debido a que pones que  el valor de la posición `i` tiene que ser mayor que el valor de la posición `j`.

Deberías cambiarlo por lo siguiente (fíjate en la condición) :

```
void FindClosest(T_PLANET *v, int n, T_PLANET *p_closest)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    j=0;
    for (i=1; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (v[i].data.distance < v[j].data.distance)
        {
            j=i;
        }
    }
    p_closest= &(v[j]);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Concuerdo, ese deberia ser el problema.

Answer (score 2):

En ese método podrían haber varias cosas que mejorar y que me parecen raras, primero que todo veo que estas usando punteros, lo cual en C#, no es muy común, así que sí los vas a usar deberías estudiar [este](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/y31yhkeb.aspx) artículo de MSDN, y usar la instrucción [`unsafe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8.aspx), pues es recomendable y una buena práctica en C#, para cuando usas punteros.

Ahora bien, me parece raro la forma en que mandas los parámetros, pues se parece mucho a los de [C++](https://ronnyml.wordpress.com/2009/07/04/vectores-matrices-y-punteros-en-c/), así que te aclaro, para mandar un vector por parámetro sería de la siguiente forma:

```
public void miMetodo(tipoDato [] nombreVariable);
public void FindClosest(T_PLANET[] v);
```

Ahora, veo que para devolver el planeta más cercano, lo asignas a un parámetro con un asterisco. Sí lo que quieres es asignarlo y que cuando termine el método, siga con el valor asignado, debes usar el `ref`, para que se pase el parámetro por [referencia](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx)

```
public void miMetodo(ref tipoDato nombreVariable);
public void FindClosest(ref T_PLANET p_closest);
```

Ahora bien, te recomiendo, que no utilices el devolver un parámetro por referencia, en un método `void`, pues deberías usarlo sí ya el método devuelve un valor y ocupas obtener otro valor que se haya modificado en el método.

Finalmente, deberías revisar la condición del `if`, pues creo que se encuentra incorrecta.

Aquí te dejo como quedaría el código, ya optimizado (teniendo en cuenta que no conozco el resto del código ni las especificaciones del programa).

```
public T_PLANTE FindClosest(T_PLANET [] v, int n)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    j=0;
    for (i=1; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (v[i].data.distance < v[j].data.distance)
        {
            j=i;
        }
    }
    p_closest= &(v[j]);
    return;
}
```

Postada:

Para recorrer un vector también puedes usar un `foreach()`, con esto podrías enviar un parámetro menos y no tendrías que preocuparte por el contador de la instrucción cíclica, [aquí](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx) te dejo información

Comment: +1 Por notar el puntero.

Answer (score 0):

en el if envez de poner:

```
v[i].data.distance > v[j].data.distance
```

deberia ser:

```
v[i].data.distance < v[j].data.distance
```

Cambiar el operador (> mayor que) por (< menor que)